# Bad auto height in ListBox

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, xaml, listbox

I have this code in XAML

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,20">
            <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="Title" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="title" Margin="9,-7,0,0" />
        </StackPanel>

        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="22,0,12,0">
            <StackPanel>
                <ListBox Name="Cities"Height="Auto" Margin="4,3,0,10">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock FontSize="40" Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

When i put items in ListBox, scroll not working. I dont want set fixed height of Listbox, because i need to support different screen resolution. I need auto height. How can i do this?

Comment: Are items going off the screen? The [ListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278062(v=VS.95).aspx) has a ScrollViewer defined in it and it will show only when items are going out of the defined area.

Comment: There is no reason for the StackPanel, unless you removed other controls for this example. And the functionality of this page could probably be done using a ListPicker in FullMode if you wanted to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the `StackPanel`, since there's only one child in it. The same goes for the `Grid` named "ContentPanel".

Remove both of them, set `Grid.Row` on the `ListBox` and adjust the margins.

The reason is that `StackPanel` is not constraining the height of its children, whatever the height your list box is asking for - stack panel provides it, even if means that the list box will not be fully shown. Since the list box is getting all the height it wants, it figures that there's no need for scrolling. This is a simplification of what is actually happens, but it's enough to understand what is happening.

`StackPanel` is kind of "evil" in that regard - it will silently give any height the child wants.

You don't have to remove the grid for the UI to work, but you also don't need it. Less nesting is better.